# Source for share of renewable energies in the electricity production of Europe

Tags: renewables, electricity-generation

I am looking for a source that shows the development of the shares of renewable energies in the electricity production in Europe. I only found statistics about the share for the end energy consumption [from Eurostat](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/databrowser/view/t2020_31/default/table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Eurostat

I wasn't aware of this data source ([Eurostat](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/data/database)), but looking around at other tables I found one for ["Electricity production capacities by main fuel groups and operator (nrg_inf_epc)"](https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=nrg_inf_epc&lang=en).

To get the results you're looking for (since the table is dynamic and I can't share a direct link), follow these steps, as shown in the screenshot below:

- Click the "+" next to "GEO"
- In the popup window, select "SIEC"
- Click "Select all" (or only those power sources you care to see)
- Click "Update" in the top right corner

> [image: How to show Eurostat energy data by source]

You can then drag the categories onto the table to list the statistics by any combination of country, year, or energy source:

> [image: Changing composition of Eurostat table]

### ENTSOE Transparency Platform

Another data source is the [ENTSOE Transparency Platform](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/generation/r2/installedGenerationCapacityAggregation/show?name=&defaultValue=true&viewType=GRAPH&areaType=BZN&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=01.01.2020+00:00|UTC|YEAR&dateTime.endDateTime=01.01.2020+00:00|UTC|YEAR&area.values=CTY|10YES-REE------0!BZN|10YES-REE------0&productionType.values=B01&productionType.values=B02&productionType.values=B03&productionType.values=B04&productionType.values=B05&productionType.values=B06&productionType.values=B07&productionType.values=B08&productionType.values=B09&productionType.values=B10&productionType.values=B11&productionType.values=B12&productionType.values=B13&productionType.values=B14&productionType.values=B20&productionType.values=B15&productionType.values=B16&productionType.values=B17&productionType.values=B18&productionType.values=B19). This doesn't have a table for all of Europe, but does provide current and historical data by country:

> [image: ENTSOE fuel source data for Austria, 2019 to 2020]

If you change the date range to cover a single year, the graphic changes to a pie chart, making it easier to visualize the relative size of each different source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and your help. Do you know a similar source for the US and China?

Comment: @Energizer you can get data on both from the U.S. Energy Information Agency, [here](https://www.eia.gov/international/data/world/electricity/electricity-capacity). I'm not familiar with other sources for data on capacity in China, but I've heard it can be hard to come by. The [International Energy Agency](https://www.iea.org/data-and-statistics/data-tables/?country=WORLD&year=2017&energy=Electricity) probably has some good data.

Comment: Thanks a lot LShaver for your help and effort. I really appreciate it.